# Where do files *really* exist after doing`adb-sync`?

Tags: android, adb, mtp, usb-debugging

I'm playing around with syncing files from my laptop to my SD card on the phone using `adb-sync`.

`adb-sync` reports successfully pushing the files to the destination.

Navigating to `/storage/9016-4EF8/Music` in `adb shell`, the new files are listed, right after the following message:

`ls: ./.android_secure: Permission denied`

Yet the new files don't appear in my file explorer on the laptop. Additionally, they are not seen by my music player.

`adb shell` (different project - see comment) otherwise lists the contents of the SD card perfectly, AFAICT. It's only the `adb-sync` transfers that incorrectly show up as not being present.

Perhaps this is related, but `adb shell` reports success when creating new files, and these files also do not appear in my file explorer (Dolphin). Creating a new file in Dolphin works fine and is correctly listed in `adb shell`!

So I believe they weren't actually transferred. Or they were transferred somewhere strange in internal memory. Where might they actually be?

Comment: Why are you using adb sync? Did you check the documentation? https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb  If you are moving music files, then there are more common methods as using the file explorer after connecting your device to your pc, for instance.  -Kf

Comment: `adb-sync` is a different project: https://github.com/google/adb-sync

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a little time to clarify my thinking about this. Actually `adb-sync` is not necessary to this discussion. The problem is actually that filesystem operations within the `adb` shell are not reflected in the view from my file manager, Dolphin. So I launched the phone's file explorer and, voila, there's the changes!

So apparently this is a problem related to the much-decried MTP protocol. I'm happy to leave it at that unless someone else has something to add.